# Characterization of certain 4-dimensional lattices

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, lattices, quadratic-forms

Let $\Lambda \subset {\bf Q}^4$ be a lattice, i.e., $\Lambda$ is a free abelian group and $\Lambda \otimes {\bf Q} = {\bf Q^4}$.

The determinants of those dilation-rotations (i.e. linear maps of ${\bf Q}^4$ represented by $rA$ with $A \in SO(4)$ and $r \in {\bf R}$) that map $\Lambda$ into itself and satisfy $\text{det}(rA) = r^4 \in ({\bf Q}^{\times})^2$, and $\text{det}(rA) = [\Lambda : rA\Lambda] \in {\bf Z}$, hence they are integral squares.

If $\Lambda = {\bf Z}^4$, all squares do indeed appear: this can, for instance, be seen by combining Lagrange's 4-square theorem with quaternionic multiplication.

Is there a characterization of all 4-dimensional lattices for which this happens?

Comment: Are you asking which quadratic forms in 4 variables represent all integral squares?

Comment: I think my question might be related to that problem, but I do not see how it could be equivalent.